# Connect a signal with a slot in a different class

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new programming with Qt, I need to connect a signal, for example, a signal triggered from a menu, with a slot in another class. This is my code:
connect(ui->actionAbrir, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(QImageProc::open()))
The application runs without errors, but the connection seems not be working when I start the application.

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. Please read this (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. I've read the thread comments below and please, please provide a minimal example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem. Moreover take 2 minutes to learn how to properly edit your post (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You'll get a much greater chance to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using Qt 4 connect syntax, you need not to specify a class name (`QImageProc`) in the SLOT macro. Also, you can check the correctness of connection by using the return value.

Update: Your object of the `QImageProc` class must be added to the `MainWindow` class by using a pointer or a member, for example:

```
//MainWindow.h:
QImageProc* m_pImageProc;

//MainWindow.cpp:    
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow) 
{ 
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //somthing like this:
    m_pImageProc = new QImageProc(/* parameters */);

    //add m_pImageProc as a third parameter to connect:
    bool ok = connect( ui->actionAbrir, SIGNAL(triggered()), m_pImageProc, SLOT(open()) );
    //...
```

See also: [New Signal Slot Syntax in Qt 5](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Comment: I made this connection in the MainWindow class, still, it doesn't work

Comment: @A.Duarte, you need to show a minimum working example: how and where do you create `actionAbrir`, where do you make `connect`, where do you define `open()`

Comment: I define open() in the class QImageProc, this is the code:
void QImageProc::open()
{

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Abrir archivo"), QDir::currentPath());

    if (!fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        this->image = QImage(fileName);        
    }
}

Comment: @A.Duarte, please add code to your question by using code tag.

Comment: This is the connection:
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    connect(ui->actionAbrir, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(open()));
    ui->actionAbrir->setShortcut(tr("Ctrl+O"));
}

Comment: @A.Duarte, ok, I have understood. Your object of QImageProc class must be added to the MainWindow class by using a pointer or a member

Comment: Like I said, I'm new in Qt, and I haven't use pointers or members. If you could explain me how to do what you said to me.

Comment: Where do I put this in the mainwindow.h: QImageProc* m_pImageProc;

Comment: @A.Duarte, you can to add it near the `Ui::MainWindow *ui;` in mainwindow.h

Comment: It gives me an error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QImageProc' with no type

Comment: @A.Duarte, you also need to `#include` to mainwindow.h the `QImageProc` header

Comment: @A.Duarte, and you need to understand that communication is making between **objects**, not between **classes**

Comment: Start with a simple example. In Qt main directory there are tons. I would suggest to start with `imageviewer` example: it's located in `Qt5.5.1/Examples/Qt-5.5/widgets/widgets/imageviewer`